# Exploding ROOT.war

Tags: java, perl, tomcat

I am copying my ROOT.war file to webapps of Tomcat 6.0 . Is there a way I can explode the file upon copying. i.e when my script copies it in the webapps .. it should explode and create ROOT directory ??

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that come to mind.

One is that the WAR file is a jar file, so you can use the [jar command](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html) to expand it.

The other is to use the Tomcat [autodeploy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment) magic. You copy the WAR file in; Tomcat notices the change, expands the WAR, and reloads it.

Answer (score 1):

The Ant task unzip/unjar will also do the trick as the WAR file is JAR/ZIP

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but you could always do:

```
cp blah.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps && unzip blah.jar
```

It assumes Unix, on windows you should be able to do something similar...

Comment: Thanks guys !!! Actually when I copied the .war into webapps .. it automatically gets explode and it's just that it was taking up a minute to get exploded !!! 
Thanks again for all the answers
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting your stuff in ROOT context.  Create a war named Foo.war and let "Foo" be the name of your context.

Comment: Why's that? When I want things at the root, which is normally the case, I put them in ROOT and it works fine.

Comment: I don't think applications belong in ROOT.  They should have their own context.

Comment: I understand that you think that. I'm asking why anybody else should think that. If you only have one app in that Tomcat, then ROOT is its own context. Works fine for me, anyhow.

Comment: It makes sense to name your context the same name as your application. Why would you put it in the ROOT context? Creating a new context allows you to have multiple applications running on different contexts.

Comment: As a note aside, if you develop a webapp and only test it when deployed in ROOT context, you won't catch the problems when someone deploys it outside of ROOT. So if you are the dev, I recommend to deploy it outside of ROOT to get aware of bugs early. Also, make sure Tomcat doesn't run on port 8080 to catch even more bugs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My WAR failed to auto-explode after I dropped it into the /webapps/ directory in tomcat7 because of read-only file permissions.

After I changed the .WAR file permissions, the WAR was exploded successfully.